# Remove characters from a string in all elements of a list

Tags: list, dictionary, haskell

Im trying to replace all strings which contain a substring by itself, in a list.
I've tried it by using the `map` function:

```
cleanUpChars = map(\w -> if isInfixOf "**" w then map(\c ->  if c == "*" then ""; else c); else w)
```

To me this reads as: map elements in a list, such that if a character of a word contains * replace it with nothing

To Haskell: "Couldnt match expected type [[Char]] -> [[Char]] with actual type [Char] in the expression: w" (and the last w is underlined)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: did you `import` the function from `Data.List`? https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=isInfixOf

Comment: too tired! thanks. my logic with this still seems to be wrong though, so edited

Comment: You don't need the semicolons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the revised question (when `isInfixOf` has been `import`ed correctly):

```
cleanUpChars = map(\w -> if isInfixOf "**" w then map(\c ->  if c == "*" then ""; else c); else w)
```

The most obvious thing wrong here is that `c` in the inner parentheses will be a `Char` (since it's the input to a function which is `map`ped over a `String`) - and characters use single quotes, not double quotes. This isn't just a case of a typo or wrong syntax, however - `""` works fine as an empty string (and is equivalent to `[]` since Strings are just lists), but there is no such thing as an "empty character".

If, as it seems, your aim is to remove all `*`s from each string in the list that contains `**`, then the right tool is `filter` rather than `map`:

```
Prelude Data.List> cleanUpChars = map(\w -> if isInfixOf "**" w then filter (/= '*') w; else w)
Prelude Data.List> cleanUpChars ["th**is", "is", "a*", "t**es*t"]
["this","is","a*","test"]
```

(Note that in the example I made up, it removes all asterisks from `t**es*t`, even the single one. This may not be what you actually wanted, but it's what your logic in the faulty version implied - you'll have to be a little more sophisticated to only remove pairs of consecutive `*`'s.)

PS I would certainly never write the function like that, with the semicolon - it really doesn't gain you anything. I would also use the infix form of `isInfixOf`, which makes it much clearer which string you are looking for inside the other:

```
cleanUpChars :: [String] -> [String]
cleanUpChars = map (\w -> if "**" `isInfixOf` w then filter (/= '*') w else w)
```

I'm still not particularly happy with that for readability - there's probably some nice way to tidy it up that I'm overlooking for now. But even if not, it helps readability imo to give the function a local name (hopefully you can come up with a more concise name than my version!):

```
cleanUpChars :: [String] -> [String]
cleanUpChars = map possiblyRemoveAsterisks
    where possiblyRemoveAsterisks w = if "**" `isInfixOf` w then filter (/= '*') w else w
```

Comment: informative & great answer, thank you! a quick which, what does the `'s around isInfixOf mean/do?

Comment: The backticks just allow you to use it in "infix form" - between the 2 arguments, rather than before them. You can do this with any function of 2 arguments, but there are some where it reads much better in infix form, and in my opinion `isInfixOf` and friends fall clearly into that category